# "Include" external .as files in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to include external code without importing a custom class in AS3. My code is getting too long and I need to find a way to segment it into logical groups of functions located in separate ActionScript files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ActionScript provides [the `include` directive](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#include) to include the source of one file inside another:

> ```
> include "[path]filename.as"
> ```
>
> Includes the contents of the specified file, as if the commands in the file are part of the calling script.

(You may also see this used as `#include`, but the `#` hasn't been required since ActionScript 2.)

Comment: I tried to do that in FlashBuilder, but it complains about the included file not being legit syntax-wise (it isn't, indeed, as I created the include file by slicing a portion of the existing class). Now the project won't compile, and I won't be able to run it. Do you know any way to work this around? Other that refactoring the big class in smaller classes?